# how to update the cart total when user adds or changes the count of an item in cart in flutter android / iOS app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, e-commerce

I have created a function to get the total value of the cart items and initialised it in the initstate of the Cart page.

I have given the code i am using, I want my cart page to update the cart total when user changes cart items or change items count as we get in existing e-commerce apps (like Flipkart or amazon) and also want the item to be deleted from cart page immediately if user taps on remove from cart button.[image]

This might be a silly question, but I am trying to figure this out from many days and I am not able to get the exact way,

I am using set state and not using BLOC pattern in my project.If I should use BLOC to overcome this issue, please tell me, so i will try modifying code using bloc.

Thanks in advance, Please help me overcome this issue.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getcarttotal();
  }
```

```
  getcarttotal() {
    print('getting cart total');
    print(cartitems.length);
    cartitems.forEach((element) {
      double value = double.parse(element.product.sellingprice);
      setState(() {
        total = total + value;
      });
      // print(value);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ValueListenableBuilder`, it is a Widget in built in Flutter which changes the state of the whole app, just after it Recieves the Data,

```
ValueNotifier<int> (Your Variable) = //Your Value..
```

You can Check this 1 minute Video : [Flutter official Video](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi_mdCYnbrwAhX3wjgGHUA_AnkQwqsBMAJ6BAgFEAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Ds-ZG-jS5QHQ&usg=AOvVaw0fY_1nQoCMUnbfjF1-qBpU)
It tells all about Value Listenable Builder.

Also You can Check this video, This Video Talks About Value Listenable Builder in Detail and currently this is most high Rated Video about the Value Listenable Builder: [Youtube Video, Talking more on the Widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YI9DQDCUvPA)

Thanks and Hope it will help.

Comment: thank you very much for taking time to solve to my problem and sharing the links, I went through it, but I want to perform a method(which recalculates the cart total) as soon as user changes the items count or delete item and change the value of cart total.

Comment: why don't You First iniitalise a Variable, then use `void increment(){itemCount++}` or something that suits your variable, And for incrementing Value of Money or SUm Total, you have to think about making a seperate variable for your each item you have in your Store, that needs serous API like work i gueess,, or if you are using something else let me know..

Comment: hi, I tried using a value notifier out publicly like this: `ValueNotifier<double> carttotal = ValueNotifier<double>(0); 
 getcarttotal() {
  double total = 0;
  cartitems.forEach((element) {
    print(element.product.sellingprice);
    print(element.count);
    double itemtotal = double.parse(element.product.sellingprice) * element.count;
    print(itemtotal);
    total = total + itemtotal;
    print(total);
  });
  carttotal.value = total;
  print(total);
}` and I called this method every time user changes the count of item. Is this good or will it cause any issue.Thankyou bro.